# Predictive Modeling on Observations Whose Features Change Over Time

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, panel-data, time-varying-covariate

The problem I'm hoping to get some input on is I have a set of observations with associated features and the outcome is whether they convert or not. That said, I acquire additional information about the observations over time and it can take weeks or months for an observation to convert. It's not the number of features changing, but more that features can change over time. For example, when an observation is first created, it might be largely NULL, but over time we learn more about the observation and are able to update fields. And this can happen multiple times and on no specific time interval. Simply when a user interacts with the observation and adds some new information.

It's easy enough to model out new observations as I know exactly what data is available for them at that point in time, but what I'm hoping to do is model out this problem such that I can provide a likelihood of conversion at any point in time. That means observations I'm scoring could be new or months old and thus have very different amounts of associated information.

I've tried "rewinding" the data such that I only have data available before a conversion for historic conversions and then everything for non-conversions, but this feels like it will be biased on newer observations that haven't had as much chance to develop and observations past a certain age are in my case far less likely to convert so time should be factored in somehow. I've been looking at things like Cox Proportional Hazards and the pip package convoys, but curious what other options there are.

Comment: Some more details could help. In which way are the number of features changing? only adding more features, or also dropping some? Do this happen only at one specifi time point, or multiple times? ...

Comment: Please add the details of this (as an edit) to the post. There can be no useful answer without detailed information.